# Is is ok to use require when declaring default parameter values?

Tags: node.js

Suppose there is a simple module:

```
module.exports.foo = (x, y, z = require('bar').z) {
   // do stuff
}
```

Now it is easy to test it by passing a mock instead of `z` without mocking modules.

Are there any downsides in this approach?

Comment: I find embedding `requires` to be (a) more difficult to read in the code, (b) more difficult to reason about (scattered dependencies, IMO, are an anti-pattern), and (c) more likely to be missed when updating (see a & b).

Comment: What tool do you use for tests?

Comment: @AlexGor I use Mocha + Sinon

Comment: @DaveNewton I totally agree. I'd better use Jest and mock module then

Answer (score 0):

It's a bad practice. This require should be call and execute module `bar` when `foo` will called first time. Instead this you can import module before, and just use value `z` as default parameter value.

```
const {z} = require('bar');

module.exports.foo = (x, y, w = z) => {
  // do stuff
}
module.exports.foo(1, 2) // call with default value
module.exports.foo(1, 2, 3) // pass third argument
```

Comment: If it was so easy :) require('bar') loads a bunch of dependencies, one of which is connecting to Redis. My goal is to unit test foo internals.

Comment: @xuesheng you can try something like this https://www.npmjs.com/package/mock-require. It's should be more clear way then dynamically require modules.

Comment: my plan was to avoid this